# Uuid will differ for every installation in ios?

Tags: ios, cordova

I am developing a Phonegap app.
If I uninstall my app and reinstall the same app, and I try to get the uuid using device.uuid, is it the same as previous? Or it creates a new uuid?

Platform : ios

Comment: UUID is a unique id for the device. If u install the app in the ios simulator, it will generate different UUID for every installation of the app. But in device, the same UUID is generated.

Comment: IOS generates different uuid on every installation: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#device.uuid

Comment: @malcurbierre i got that using your link. Thanks. Can you post this as answer?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're referring to the "identifierForVendor" method, as "uniqueIdentifier" is deprecated since iOS 7.

[Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#jumpTo_7) states that the UUID will be reset in every installation of the Applications:

> The value in this property remains the same while the app (or another app from the same vendor) is installed on the iOS device. The value changes when the user deletes all of that vendor’s apps from the device and subsequently reinstalls one or more of them. The value can also change when installing test builds using Xcode or when installing an app on a device using ad-hoc distribution. Therefore, if your app stores the value of this property anywhere, you should gracefully handle situations where the identifier changes.

What you can do, is to save the value to the KeyChain on the first installation, and use that value ever after. It should persist through uninstall / reinstall.